# Delete procedure wont run and gives errors?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, package

Ive created a procedure to delete data from three tables that are all linked with foreign keys but it does not run. here is the procedure.

```
PROCEDURE remove_customer (customer_id VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM order_line
WHERE  order_line.order_id = placed_order.order_id;
DELETE FROM placed_order
WHERE placed_order.customer_id = customer.customer_id;
DELETE FROM customer
WHERE customer.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;
total_customers := total_customers - 1;
END;
```

And here is the structure for the three tables. anyone any idea why i get errors?

```
customer(
    Customer_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Country VARCHAR(15),
    First_Name  VARCHAR(30),
    Last_Name   VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT  pk_customer PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)
);


    placed_order(
    order_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    order_date  VARCHAR(15),
    fk1_Customer_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk2_Employee_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk3_order_type_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  pk_placed_order PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);


    order_line(
    order_line_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk1_order_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk2_product_id  INTEGER NOT NUL,
    CONSTRAINT  pk_order_line PRIMARY KEY (order_line_id)
);
```

Here are the two errors its throwing back.

ORA-00904: "PLACED_ORDER"."ORDER_ID": invalid identifierCompilation failed,line 30

ORA-00904: "CUSTOMER"."CUSTOMER_ID": invalid identifierCompilation failed,line 32

Comment: If you don't already, I suggest you define real foreign keys on your tables.

Comment: H, yes there already defined but thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just refer to columns in other tables in a DELETE statement.  Each statement needs to start from the parameter value customer_id.  This should do what you want:

```
PROCEDURE remove_customer (customer_id VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN

  DELETE FROM order_line
  WHERE  order_line.order_id in
  ( SELECT order_id FROM placed_order
    WHERE placed_order.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id
  );

  DELETE FROM placed_order
  WHERE placed_order.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;

  DELETE FROM customer
  WHERE customer.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;

  total_customers := total_customers - 1;

END;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that makes sense, one thing im getting a SQL command not ended properly, is it missing a ';' in the first delete from?

Comment: hmm fairly strange when it didn't have the ; its just have that error and now I've added it its giving me loads or errors?


ORA-00904: "ORDER_LINE"."ORDER_ID": invalid identifierCompilation failed


PLS-00302: component 'CUSTOMER_ID' must be declaredCompilation failed


PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PLACED_ORDER"."CUSTOMER_ID": invalid identifierCompilation failed

any idea?

Comment: You have to make sure the column names you use in the statements match the actual column names - for example `order_line.order_id` should be `order_Line.fk1_order_id` according to your table definitions.